# How can I do import java class from another java file where class have access "package"

Tags: java, import

explane me please how can I do import class in case below.
I have two java file (this is example). First:

```
package com.mypackage.task

public class TaskF7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}

class Database {
}

class Employee {
}
```

Second file:

```
package com.mypackage.test

import com.mypackage.task.TaskF7.*; // import does not work
import com.mypackage.task.TaskF7.Employee; // import does not work

public class TestF7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testTask();
    }

    // so, my IDEA mark as red <Employee> below
    public static void testTask(List<Employee> expected, List<Employee> actual> ) {
    if (Arrays.deepEquals(expected.toArray(), actual.toArray())) {
        System.out.println("passed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed: expected " + expected + ", actual " + actual);
    }
}
```

class Employee have is package access.

Please note:  in task write: "place all solution classes in one file (not as inner classes). " Not inner classes

Comment: This is usually why you would put these in the same package.

Comment: You can't, unless the importing class is in the same package.

Comment: I can't change package structure, sorry. See below how I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a class with package access outside the package. You could change Employee class to public or change the package of my.package.test

Answer (score 0):

You can access this through make it "Inner Class" but you should make it public

```
public class TaskF7 {
   public class Employee {
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}

public class TaskF7{
   public static void testTask(List<TaskF7.Employee> expected,   
                               List<TaskF7.Employee> actual ) {
      if (Arrays.deepEquals(expected.toArray(), actual.toArray())) {
          System.out.println("passed");
      } else {
          System.out.println("failed: expected " + expected + ", actual " +   
          actual);

      }
   }
}
```

Now your IntellijIDEA will not give any red sign underline error  :)

Comment: thank you for answer, but in task write: "place all solution classes in one file (not as inner classes). " Not inner classes

Comment: but can you  thumbs up this question.. bcz I have not seen explanation  in your question

Comment: @Jack That constraint is not stated in your question. Please fix it so it is.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way:
1.

```
 public static void testTask(Object expected, Object actual> ) {
    if (expected.equals(actual)) {
        System.out.println("passed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed: expected " + expected + ", actual " + actual);
}
```

2.

```
Class Employee {

    @Override 
    equals(){
    }

    @Override
    hashCode(){
    }
}
```